# Inserting non-geotagged terrestrial photos in ArcGIS using coordinates/file path in table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, data-driven-pages

using ArcMap, I want to create data driven pages of road signs along a highway with terrestrial photos that are NOT geo-tagged (Two photos per road sign). The image names/Network folder paths/coordinates are stored in the feature attribute table of signs. [image: Table]

My wish is that the data driven sheets will show these photos, which are automatically inserted near the POINT feature (road signs) they belong to (in data view or layout). The images are on a network folder. So, basically, I wondering how I can implement a script/tool to look inside the table, look at the feature, then the network link, pull the image and insert it next to the feature in layout view or data view. Since there are two photos, they need to be "staggered" (not overlap with one another) so they don't fall on top of each other.

Is there a way to do this in ArcMap (or other method)?

There are 907 signs with approximately 1700 photos.

I'm using ArcGIS Advanced 10.2 with Spatial/3D Analyst extensions.